# How to write HDF5 dataset in C++ instead of C

Tags: c++, c, hdf5

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors. This is code to read dataset from 400+ files with for loop to input in an big array.

```
float (*HaloPos)[3];//3D-positon(x-y-z)

int Nhalo= 1000000;//Suppose there are 1000000 particles in total number.

void readh5(int numfiles)
{
 char fname[256];
 int i, npart_cum;
 

  hid_t hdf5_file, hdf5_grp, hdf5_dataspace_in_file;
  hid_t hdf5_datatype, hddf5_dataspace_in_memory, hdf5_dataset;
  hsize_t dims[2], count[2];
  hsize_t start[2];


  for(int task = 0; task < numfiles; task ++) 
      { 
      sprintf(fname,"%s.%d.hdf5",FILE_DIR,task); 
      cout<<"file name is"<<fname<<endl;
      cout.flush();
      read_header_attributes_in_hdf5(fname);
       
     
      cout<<"npart = "<<header.npart<<endl;
      cout.flush();
      

      if(task == 0) 
      { 
      Nhalo   = header.npartTotal[1]; 
      npart_cum[1] = 0;
      }
    if(header.npart[1] > 0){
      Group grp = file.openGroup("/PartType1");
      read_halo(file, grp, task, npart_cum);
      grp.close();
    }
    cout<<"task="<<task<<"halo particles have been read in."<<endl;
    cout.flush();
    file.close();
    
  
      npart_cum += header.npart[1];
    
    }
}


static void read_halo(H5File file, Group grp, int task, int npre)
{
  hid_t hdf5_dataset;
  /*--*/
  if(task == 0)
    if(!(HaloPos =  malloc(sizeof(float)*Nhalo*3)))
      exit(100);
  printf("allocate positions\n"); 
  fflush(stdout); 

  hdf5_dataset = H5Dopen(hdf5_grp,"Coordinates");
> get_float3(hdf5_file, hdf5_grp, hdf5_dataset, &HaloPos[npre][0]);
  H5Dclose(hdf5_dataset);
}

static void read_header_attributes_in_hdf5(char *fname)
{

 hid_thdf5_file,G hdf5_headergrphdf5_attribute;

  hdf5_file = H5Fopen(fname, H5F_ACC_RDONLY, H5P_DEFAULT);
  hdf5_headergrp = H5Gopen(hdf5_file, "/Header");

  hdf5_attribute = H5Aopen_name(hdf5_headergrp, "NumPart_ThisFile");
  H5Aread(hdf5_attribute, H5T_NATIVE_INT, &header.npart);
  H5Aclose(hdf5_attribute);

 
  
}

static void get_float3(H5File file, Group grp, DataSet dset, float *fvec){
  /* Open the dataset */
 hid_t hdf5_datatype, hdf5_dataspace;
  H5T_class_t hdf5_class;
  H5T_order_t hdf5_order;
  int status_n, rank;

  hsize_t dims_out[2];
  herr_t status;

  hdf5_datatype = H5Dget_type(hdf5_dataset); 
  hdf5_class    = H5Tget_class(hdf5_datatype);
  if(hdf5_class != H5T_FLOAT)
    exit(53);
  hdf5_dataspace = H5Dget_space(hdf5_dataset); /* dataspace handle */
  rank = H5Sget_simple_extent_ndims(hdf5_dataspace);
  if(rank != 2)
    exit(54);

  status_n       = H5Sget_simple_extent_dims(hdf5_dataspace, dims_out, NULL);
  
  if(dims_out[1] != 3)
    exit(55);

  status = H5Dread(hdf5_dataset, H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, 
      H5P_DEFAULT, fvec);

  H5Tclose(hdf5_datatype);
}
}
```

> The code is not complete, but the main thing I want to ask everyone is how to use dataset.read instead of H5Dread to read the data and add after the array after one loop

In my limited experience with C++
actually I tried using vector replace array, but I want to know how to write in c++
After I changed background in c++. The code I just changed

```
status = H5Dread(hdf5_dataset, H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, 
      H5P_DEFAULT, fvec);
```

to

```
dataset.read(fvec,datatype);
```

And I found the dataset read defination is different in c and c++
in c++

```
void read   (   void *  buf,
const DataType &    mem_type,
const DataSpace &   mem_space = DataSpace::ALL,
const DataSpace &   file_space = DataSpace::ALL,
const DSetMemXferPropList &     xfer_plist = DSetMemXferPropList::DEFAULT 
)       const

void read   (   H5std_string &  buf,
const DataType &    mem_type,
const DataSpace &   mem_space = DataSpace::ALL,
const DataSpace &   file_space = DataSpace::ALL,
const DSetMemXferPropList &     xfer_plist = DSetMemXferPropList::DEFAULT 
)       const
```

and in c

```
H5Dread (hid_t dset_id, hid_t mem_type_id, hid_t mem_space_id, hid_t file_space_id, hid_t dxpl_id, void *buf)
```

Could someone help about how to write in c++?Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is more of a code review thing. It is too much code to quickly give an answer. At least in C++ I would not expect to see malloc being used (even no new/delete), but std::make_unique or std::vector. HaloPos would probably be a struct with 3 named floats? And char[] buffers should probably be converted to std::string if they represent text or std::array/std::vector of std::uint8_t if its binary data. Also get rid of global variables like (Nhalo), either you have a constant or you pass the size some other way.

Comment: In general, I would learn what I could from C++, C++ really is a different language . Have a look at [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [string formatting](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format). Learn about (const) references, constexpr constants. Then just take all that knowlegde an write new C++ from scratch (just see your "C" code as documentation on fileformat)